# C# ASCII based game

Tags: c#, graphics, ascii

I'm trying to dip my toe into game programming, C# is the language I'm most comfortable with and what I want to use.

I've purchased a book and it's very good with the basic concepts but it's using GDI, bitmaps and sprites. I'm no artist and I'd like to concentrate on game play rather than eye candy, I'm more than happy with 'Dwarf Fortress' style of presentation.

DF doesn't seem to be a Console app (to my untrained eye). My question is can I access this 'graphic mode' from C# and if so how? Any tips links tutorials would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Short question: Are you aware of the fact, that you can create more than just console applications with C#? There is WinForms and WPF, with WPF even supporting hardware accelerated 3D programming.

Comment: I did a search once for a 2D game engine and the search came up with this. http://www.mangatutorials.com/forum/showthread.php?742-The-Ultimate-Indie-Game-Developer-Resource-List .If you are afraid of drawing then you can create some sprites with ASCII characters and then replace them with more advance graphics as you see fit.

Comment: Do you have a general idea of what the game will look like, gameplay-wise?

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for replying. Yes I'm very aware and have written many programs using both WinForms and WPF, all tools for internal use at the company I work at and for our customer base. Games however are a new area for me and will be using ideas and methods I'm not use to in my normal coding life.

Comment: Hi Yorye, the game is still in my head but a 2D map (similar to DF) with the similar capabilites (terraforming etc like mining, digging). I'm not looking to make a DF clone but to describe what I'm looking to do in short its easier to say 'like DF'.

Answer (score 2):

Writing a 2D game in C# is actually very simple.  Try with XNA.  A simple tutorial that got me started with 2D was this...

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started

It basically covers a simple 2D side scroller but what you get from the tutorial will be useful in your DF like game.  It requires you to create some graphics but like you said, those graphics need not be fancy.  Drawing simple sprites will be easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Console games are a great way to enter the game making business or hobby, once you are very comfortable with c#, try to go to xna or unity. Xna is not being developed anymore and I don't find it very pleasant and prefer unity over it, but many people differ from me so please try it out for yourself. Unity is a 2D and 3D game engine wit a free and paid version. It can be complicated at first but very well made. You can develop in c# and many more languages with unity and it is a lot more flexible than xna.